# How to count mysql with using group by PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

How to count mysql with using group by PHP ?

When i test this code it's echo `1`

How to do for echo `3` (by count country)?

This is my table_test

```
_____________________
|__id___|__country__|
|__1____|____usa____|
|__2____|____usa____|
|__3____|___china___|
|__4____|____uk_____|
```

This is my code.

```
<?PHP
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_test GROUP BY country");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
mysql_free_result($result);
$all_country = $row[0];
echo $all_country;
?>
```

Comment: `mysql_fetch_row()` = fetching first row only. You'll want to loop through the fetching with `while()` or `mysql_fetch_array()`. **BUT:** you should stop using `mysql_*` functions as the library is deprecated. Look into [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) & [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*` API. use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`insteat!

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
SELECT Country,COUNT(*) FROM table_test GROUP BY country
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Use `mysqli_*` API instead of `mysql_*` API

2) Use `mysqli_num_rows` to get total row returned

```
$sql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_test GROUP BY country";

 if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
 {
    $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
 }

echo $rowcount; // print 3
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code for counting rows of selected query

```
 <?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_test GROUP BY country");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$all_country = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo $all_country;
?>
```